# What is the default unit for slope in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, slope

When using Raster Based Terrain Analysis on QGIS for creating a slope layer, what units are the used in the output? Degrees or %?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you create a slope layer from `Raster` > `Terrain Analysis` > `Slope`, the output layer will have ***degrees*** as units of measurement.

Instead, using the **Slope** GDAL tool from the **Processing Toolbox** will allow expressing the slope as a percent, instead of degrees (they are the default unit):

[image]

There is also the **Slope, aspect, curvature** SAGA tool from the **Processing Toolbox**, which allows expressing the output using radians too (but I never tested it):

[image]